# Get text of all selected rows

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I am trying to get the text of all the selected rows when a button is pressed.   Here's what I have so far:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedRows addObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text];
}
```

selectedRows is an array.

Here is my button press function where I need access to the checked row titles:

```
- (IBAction)selectList:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedRows);
}
```

This doesn't work for me because if a user unchecks a row and then clicks the submit button - it is not reflected in the array.  I would appreciate some help with this.  thanks.

Comment: How do you populate your cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dealing with keeping tabs on what is/isn't selected at any given moment, why not just wait until it's time to select the list to generate it and let the table keep track of what's selected. (provided it isn't some massive amount of data) You could loop through the index paths of your table's selected cells and pull the string you're looking for directly out of the datasource.

```
- (IBAction)selectList:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfText = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSIndexPath *idx in self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
        [arrayOfText addObject:dataSource[idx.row]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfText);
}
```

Comment: +1, it's a waste to build your own tracking of row selection with the table view does it already

Answer (score 0):

You could add a didDeselectRowAtIndexPath function and remove the item from the array.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[selectedRows removeObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text];
}
```